Account creation
I was under the impression that the 1st transaction for every account would be a transaction containing some sort of account-creation instruction for that account.
However, I found this one that doesn't appear to follow that pattern 9xNMrHy3VPevZYQTrTednXGXuimG9CgN88HtwWu1Um9k.  When I call getSignaturesForAddress it returns just 3 items, and the 1st one (wct...zxQ) doesn't appear to contain any sort of account creation instructions.
What have I misunderstood please?

The first transaction for every account is just that: a transaction that contains that account in some way. An account can be used in all sorts of ways, but typically it'll be used as a plain signer, or an account storing data, which would require a signature too.
In some other examples, if I create a token account owned by another wallet, but that wallet has never been used, then the wallet account will be in the transaction, but it will be used as neither a signer nor a data-storage account.
